# Does the following sentence mean I perfectly accept other today?

Tags: tenses

Does the following sentence speak of a process, a movement toward acceptance?

Or does it imply the speaker is already perfectly accepting today?

> I create a world of radical acceptance by accepting myself, others, and what is.

Comment: What is the source and context? Did it really say "I create of a world ..." or did it say "I create a world ..."?

Comment: @Anton thanks for catching my error there, it was "I create a world". The source is actually a sentence I wrote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That sentence could go either way, or even both at the same time. The present tense in English can express habitual action:

> I eat eggs for breakfast.

or planned action:

> We now say a prayer for the departed.